# org.ektorp.DbAccessException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: java, csv, timeout, couchdb, converters

Hello i have this code and try to export a view from my couchdb which has more that 1.5 million documents, on the server from my university

public class main
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws MalformedURLException

```
{
    HttpClient httpclient = new StdHttpClient.Builder().url("http://localhost:5984").socketTimeout(100000).build();

    CouchDbInstance dbInstance = new StdCouchDbInstance(httpclient);
    CouchDbConnector db = new StdCouchDbConnector("twitterdb2",dbInstance);
      ViewQuery query = new ViewQuery().designDocId("_design/retweetzahl").viewName("retweetzahl").group(true); StreamingViewResult data = db.queryForStreamingView(query); try { CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\idanzahl.csv"));long counter = 1;String[] read = new String[] {"doc_id","retweetcount"};writer.writeNext(read);writer.flush(); for(Row row : data){
read = new String[] {row.getKey(), row.getValue()};
writer.writeNext(read);
writer.flush();
System.out.println(counter);
counter++; } System.out.println("Fertig ");data.close();writer.close(); }catch(Exception socketTimeoutException){



}
    }

}
```

But it dont worked, i get the message about the Exception in thread "main" org.ektorp.DbAccessException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

can someone give me a advice, it worked on the small database with 500.000 documents

Comment: increase socket timeout value?

Comment: you could try hitting the url with curl or a web browser to see how long the query takes?